# ContinueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent: method is not being called?

Tags: objective-c, tracking, uislider, uitouch, cgrect

I have a custom UIView class. Inside that view, there is an image view. (I'm making a UISlider from scratch).

I am trying to get the image view -- the thumb of the slider -- to move across the view. Below is the code from the UIView class

```
- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];


    if ( CGRectContainsPoint(self.thumb.frame, touchPoint))

        self.thumb.center = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x, self.thumb.center.y);

    return YES;

}
```

When I place my finger on the thumb of the slider and try to drag it, nothing happens. However, when I touch outside the thumb of the slider, drag my finger to the thumb without letting go, and then try dragging the thumb, it works fine.

How can I modify my code so that the method will be called when someone holds the thumb and tries to drag it?

Comment: Triple-post: [Not detecting UITouch in continueTrackingWithTouch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110896/not-detecting-uitouch-in-continuetrackingwithtouch) and [continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent not being called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113951/continuetrackingwithtouchwithevent-not-being-called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have user interaction enabled on your image view, which is in turn not relaying the touch events to the backing logic view. Do something like this:

```
self.thumb.userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

Put that in whatever init method you are using and the thumb view will not interrupt the touch events anymore.